# Can I run 2 transformers in series?

Tags: transformer, high-voltage, series

I need a 15kV or higher power supply. I found 2 used neon sign transformers rated at 10kv. Can I use both of them and connect the secondary coils in series to get 20kV?

I am not sure if 15kV isn't overkill. I need voltage that is big enough to ignite a spark between 5-10mm. I read that the value is 30kV/cm, so I assume 15kV is good enough to jump 5mm.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically high-voltage (and 10kV is high voltage) neon sign transformers have a center-tapped secondary and the midpoint is grounded (MPG). See this [reference](http://www.neon-lighting.com/articles/neon%20transformer%20FAQ.htm).

You thus cannot usefully connect the outputs of this type of transformer in series, the output will be partially shorted.

Comment: or you could isolate/disconnect the center taps and ground the connected terminals

Comment: @ratchetfreak The insulation would not be reliable even if that was possible. Better (and safer) to buy a 15kV transformer.

Comment: This is bad news. What else can I use to get 20kV pulsed DC?! Ignition coil?

Comment: 10kV transformer, diode and capacitor, but that's almost another question.

Comment: @ratchetfreak Can you post an answer about how to do that? I found this link: http://www.rtftechnologies.org/emtech/nst.htm